# How to display a different toast message on multiple instances of SpannableString?

Tags: java, android

I am getting data from a json file and I want to have a different toast (on click) for each spannable string on the textview.

It works but it only shows the same toast message for each spannablestring on the textview; specifically its only showing the very last currentLocation on the json file.

```
            for(int k = 0; k < 8;k++) {
                spannableString1 = new SpannableString("Destination: " + canningTownArrivals1.get(k).destinationName); //spannable string is in the scope of the for loop,
                ClickableSpan clickableSpan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view1) {
                        for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++){
                            Toast.makeText(CanningTownActivity.this,canningTownArrivals1.get(c).currentLocation,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                };
                spannableString1.setSpan(clickableSpan1,0,canningTownArrivals1.get(k).length() + 13, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                textViewResult1.append(spannableString1);
                textViewResult1.append(
                        "\nTime: " + canningTownArrivals1.get(k).timeToStation + " mins\n");

                textViewResult1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                }
```

I want it to show a different currentLocation on each spannableString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for(int k = 0; k < 8;k++) {
            spannableString1 = new SpannableString("Destination: " + canningTownArrivals1.get(k).destinationName); //spannable string is in the scope of the for loop,

            spannableString1.setSpan(createClickableSpan(canningTownArrivals1.get(k).currentLocation),0,canningTownArrivals1.get(k).length() + 13, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textViewResult1.append(spannableString1);
            textViewResult1.append(
                    "\nTime: " + canningTownArrivals1.get(k).timeToStation + " mins\n");

            textViewResult1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }


private ClickableSpan createClickableSpan(final String location) {
    return new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(CanningTownActivity.this,location,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };
}
```